# A property of faithful Lie group action $G$ on $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold that $G$ as Lie group acts on it. Assume the Lie group action is faithful (if $g\cdot x = x$ for all $x\in M$ then $g = e$).

Define the map $$\varphi_x:G\to M\\ g\mapsto g\cdot x$$

If given a $Y\in T_eG$ such that $d_e\varphi_x (Y) = 0$ for all $x\in M$ , Can we deduce that $Y = 0$? I don't know how to apply the faithful condition. It's sufficient to provide an idea.